Getting 405 error when making POST request with URLRequest
I'm trying to make a POST request to a newly deployed vercel server. I am having trouble with the request in POSTMan and am getting error 500 when I try to request it from postman. My swift code only returns error 405. Here is my code:
    func callRequest() {
        let full_path: String = "https://suno-api-six-henna.vercel.app/api/generate"
        let json: [String: Any] = ["prompt": "A popular heavy metal song about war, sung by a deep-voiced male singer, slowly and melodiously.",
                                   "make_instrumental": "false", "wait_audio": "true"]
        
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

        if let url = URL(string: full_path) {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            do {
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    //This converts the optionals in to non optionals that could be used further on
                    //Be aware this will just return when something goes wrong
                    guard let data = data, let response = response, error == nil else{
                        print("Something went wrong: error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unkown error")")
                        return
                    }
                    print(response)
                    let test = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                    print(test)
                }
                
                task.resume()
            }
        }
    }

Feel free to use POSTMan or make a request to the link in the full_path variable. Please help me debug! Could it be the headers?

Note, you should be using let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){...}

@workingdogsupportUkraine Good call! Now I'm getting internal server error 500

@workingdogsupportUkraine Now I'm getting error 504

try updating the SUNO_COOKIE

Did you set your SUNO_COOKIE? Visiting https://suno-api-six-henna.vercel.app/api/get_limit tells me that you haven't.

@Sweeper I did set the cookie

The cookie might have expired I think. Try getting a new one from https://suno.com/.

Now I'm getting error 504 and the function is timing out. This is an error on vercel... anyone know how to increase the max duration of functions in vercel?

I'm not familiar with vercel servers, but according to the suno docs,
you could try getting a APITOKEN and adding
request.setValue("Bearer \(APITOKEN)", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
